# How persist geo coordinates

Tags: bigdata

I am making a app that récord geo coordinates from a gps phone. Later with these geo coordinates i will show the route in a map.

What is the best way to persist this info? Which Database do you recommend?

I am asking this question because for big trips, the geo coordinates are going to be to much records, and is going to impact in performance.

Any help will appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A database might be just needed if you want to other things with coordinates.
There several solutions available:

- [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org) with [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) (opensource)
- [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/overview/index.html) with [Oracle Spatial](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/spatial/overview/index.html?origref=http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/overview/index.html)
- Microsoft SQL Server with Spatial extension
- [SQLite (Spatialite)](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index)

You can combine them with output systems e.g.

- [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome)
- [mapserver](http://mapserver.org/)
- [ArcGIS Online](http://www.esri.de/products/arcgis/arcgisonline/index.html)
- [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/)
- ...

To display your routes.